# VS Code runs .java files without the producing .class files

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have some basic java knowledge and i decided to switch from Intellij to VS Code. I know how to compile and run a java file (which may use other imported .java files) from the terminal, but i want to run a java program using the run icon inside vs code.
I'm not a 100% sure, but i think that in order to run a java program inside vs code you need a extension. For this reason i downloaded the Java extension pack. Note that i already have installed the latest jdk on my computer.

After i installed the plugin, i could run the program using the "run without debugging"/clicking in the run icon. However, no .class files are produced. I control+h but there isnt any hidden folder that vs code may drop the .class files.
How does the program run in the first place?
How can i config vs code in order to compile the java files before running the one that has the main function?

Answer (score 1):

If your project is a folder containing Java source files. And no build tools(Maven/Gradle) are used.

If that is the case, you can trigger the command `Java: Configure Classpath`, then find the section `output` and then set a relative path to your workspace.

> The output files are by default stored inside the workspace storage.

If after triggering the command, what you see is the native vs code setting page. Then try to search `java.project.outputPath` and then set a relative path to it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you run a java file normally, you compile it with `javac` and then run it with `java` (or something along those lines, there are many different variations of possible ways to do it). If you go ahead and try, it is possible to run `java filename.java` and skip the normal `javac` step. In the case of VSCode, it will differ based on what extensions you have, but some may run the code with a simple `java filename.java` and others may have different settings set. If you take a look at your extension preferences as well as your preferences for java by searching your settings, there may be an option, such as "Java Source Paths" enabled which changed where compiled files are saved by VSCode.